# bash datetime concatenated with space

Tags: bash, timestamp

I am trying to print the current date time with a space that looks like this:

```
2015-10-13 00:00:00 ( YYYY-dd-mm H:m:S)
```

I see that this works: `` dte1=`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%s` ``.  So does `` dte2=`date +%Y_%m_%d` ``

But I dont seem to get the one character space between the date and the timestamp.  I tried concatenation , but that only results in `2015-10-1300:00:00` i.e., without the space.

Please help

Comment: how about `dte1=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T")` with the quotes to enable the space.

Comment: thanks.  that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2015-10-13 14:48:17

date +"%FORMAT %FORMAT" # just an example with space
```

Anything other than %FORMAT remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to quote the argument:

```
dte1=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")
echo $dte1
2015-10-13 20:41:1444761690
```